# Are SQL Server Database Ids always positive?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Are SQL Server database Ids always positive?

As in the dbid from sysdatabases.

```
SELECT name, dbid 
  FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

This question has nothing to do with identity columns or primary keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited, since you changed the question.

In this query: SELECT name, dbid from master.dbo.sysdatabases
The value of dbid will ALWAYS be positive, since it is defined as a 1,1 identity.

Answer (score 3):

They don't have to be, but the general practice is to make them.  You can easily create a Primary Key that is an indentity with a negative Identity Increment.  You would also not make it an identity and give it a negative value as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is some software (Microsoft Dynamics) that will not allow negative keys on integer fields that are more than 2 bytes. Other that that, I see no reason to limit the identity column to positive numbers when the column is not used as an external identity. i.e. Customer ID

Answer (score 0):

They don't necessarily have to be, but they usually are.

You might be interested to read this discussion on MSDN: [Advantage/Disadvantages of Negative Identity Values](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/3b7215ae-e65b-4e7d-a262-75cc3fe5ad1a)