# Negative database IDs in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can database Ids be negative in SQL Server?

I know that you can have a total 32767 (for both 32 bit and 64 bit) [(Maximum Capacity SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

I know that the first few database Ids are reserved for master, model, msdb and tempdb and 32767 is the hidden system resource database.

I have never seen a negative database Id but I would like to confirm that it is not possible.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253649/are-sql-server-database-ids-always-positive

Comment: Example when negative IDs might be used is to keep data required for the QA team separate. For example have "imaginary_country_ID = -2" and all its related date (stores, customers, etc.) also having negative IDs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, they can be, but they almost never are.

In the master DB, the id column in the sysdatabases table is defined as an identity column with seed 1 and increment 1. That means that, by default, SQL Server will always assign a positive DBID for any database you create.

However, it is possible to change,you can specify negative seeds and increments for identity columns,so you can reset the identity column of the sysdatabases table to -1, -1 and the next database you create will have ID -1, then -2, etc. -1 is a perfectly valid 16-bit integer value and so the identity field should have no trouble. You *may* have an issue with SQL Server naively checking the number of DBs it manages by checking the max DBID. I would not expect MSS to make that check in such a stupid way, but stranger things have happened, and I've never seen an instance with more than a couple dozen DBs on it.

Comment: You will have a really, really hard time changing the identity properties for a system table (at least in 2005+).

Answer (score 0):

In practice you should probably think about using bigint instead of int if you think you might run out of identity values rather than negative values. However, I have seen them used occasionaly when the table warrants some  particular special cases. These are generally input using set identity_insert on.

For instance in one place where I worked, we had negative ids in for our system users. Since data entered in our person table was marked by who entered them it was easy to exclude the system entries (from imports and the like) from the ones entered by actual people which is helpful in researching data problems. Sure we could easily look to see if id was 13856799 but < 0 is easier to remember.